# What's the proof that the polarization occurs to the electric field of the light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, polarization

What's the proof of the light polarization that it happens to the electric field and not the magnetic field? How did Malus discover that the light is polarized although he didn't see the waves polarizing!

Comment: All components of the EM field - electric and magnetic field vectors - are polarised. The electric and magnetic field vectors of a plane wave are orthogonal, so the magnetic field's polarisation mimics that of the electric field. What you may be thinking is that when an plane wave is incident on an interface, we think of it as being a superposition of one kind of wave with its electric field alone in the plane of polarisation, and another with its magnetic field in the plane of polarisation. So, certain polarisations have zero magnetic field *in the plane of polarisation*.

Comment: Also, most means that we have to measure polarization depend primarily on electric field interactions, so we tend not to think of the magnetic field.  Some polarization effects (e.g. [the Faraday effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect)) involve on the magnetic field rather than the electric field.

Comment: This is a re-wording of your earlier question. FYI It's customary, and preferred, that you edit the previous question, or delete it and ask a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the magnetic field polarize when polarizing light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107562/)

Comment: Before the advent of polarizing filters, polarization could be observed with reflected (or scattered) light.