# Is it the magnetic or electric components of light that get polarized?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Since polarization filters light in all directions except one, the electric or magnetic field should be filtered, right?

Comment: Have a look at the answer by Chris here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107562/why-doesnt-the-magnetic-field-polarize-when-polarizing-light  and the comment to that answer

Comment: I think you’re asking a substantiell question. From the answer from Othin it’s obvious that it seems not to play any role in physics life, which field component, the electric or the magnetic field is influenced by the polarizer.  Do you want to ask about experimental evidence of which Feld component is rotated in which direction after the polarizer? (Otherwise I will ask.)

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic waves can be thought of as coupled oscillations of electric and magnetic fields, which oscillate perpendicularly, related by Maxwell equations, so that we can actually find the polarization of, say, the magnetic field from the polarization of the electric field. We usually only bother to specify one of them, and, by convention, we mean by "polarization" of an EM wave, that of the electric field.

Comment: So polarized light has both the components in it, right?

Comment: Yes, polarization won't destroy the magnectic component, it will change in a way that allows it orthogonal to the electric field.